# Assign types to renamed destructured variables returned from a function

Tags: typescript

I want to set types on the response of this function call where I am creating new variables

```
const { error: mixesError, result:mixes } = await getArtist(name);
```

I have tried the following

```
 const {
        error: mixesError,
        result: mixes,
      }: { mixesError: string; mixes: any } = await getArtist(name);
```

but receive the following error

```
Type '{ result: any[]; error?: undefined; } | { error: any; result?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type '{ mixesError: string; mixes: any; }'.
  Type '{ result: any[]; error?: undefined; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ mixesError: string; mixes: any; }': mixesError, mixes
```

I have also tried the following

const {
error: mixesError,
result: mixes,
}: { error: string; result: any } = await getArtist(name);

Comment: You're not renaming properties. You're creating variables with different names.

Answer (score 0):

You're not renaming properties. You're creating variables with different names. The type of the result of `getArtist()` is still:

```
{ error: string; result: any }
```

… which means that you need the following:

```
const { error: mixesError, result: mixes }: { error: string; result: any } = await getArtist(name);
```